# Best practices when modifying a function to add extra fields that are used in specific areas only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking for pointers for best practices for a situation where i have a generic function e.g. GetActiveUserDetails() that does some logic and returns some details about users in a snapshot class from the db to populate dropdowns across various pages.

In majority of places this is sufficient but now I need to extend functionality by also getting an extra field for a set of specific pages that was not previously returned by the stored proc being called.

The way I see it I can modify the stored proc, have it return the extra field as well, and modify the snapshot class to also include the extra field. The other option is to just use the original function/stored proc and then join it with the field I want from the table using LINQ in a separate function and return it in a new class (probably extending the original snapshot with the extra field?).

I feel like the issue with the first option is that I'm retrieving an extra field that won't be used except in specific pages which means that there will just be extra unnecessary data being returned in a lot of situations but it does feel more simple. The snapshot class is being used by other functions that won't be modified so in those functions it just won't set that field but should I avoid adding a field that normally be used in the snapshot? Are there any specific principles I should be paying attention to or am I just overthinking a simple change?

Comment: Consider editing your question so that you aren't asking about a "best practice". That implies an opinion, and this site seriously frowns on opinion-based questions. Asking for programming pointers (which is what you are really asking for here) is ok.

Comment: There are other aspects to the questions asked in this question that seem bent to soliciting opinions: "...should I avoid..." "Are there any specific principles I should be paying attention to...." etc. It also seems unfocused.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

There's nothing that says that a single stored procedure must always return a resultset of a same shape.  I once maintained a massive stored procedure that had five separate resultsets (it implemented a persistent state machine) - I do not miss working on that stored procedure.

So, you could make a stored procedure that takes as one of its input parameters a flag, "Simple" or "Complex".  In the stored procedure, if the user is asking for "Simple", you do a simple query, get a handful of results and return them. But if the flag is set to "Complexc, then you can do a more complex database operation and return back a larger set of results.

On the C# side have two different classes, one that represents the simple data and one (likely a subclass of the first) to represent the combination of of the simple and complex data.

You don't mention how you do your database access so I can't show you an example, but, fir example, doing this with Dapper would be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Fields that are only filled-in when certain magic is right but left uninitialized in other cases are a source of bugs.

Fields that are in some cases needed but in other cases redundant increase the overall entropy of the design. One day one such field might stop being used, (become redundant in all cases,) and you would have no way of knowing.

Ideally, a function that retrieves information should be told what information to retrieve, just as the SQL SELECT statement allows you to be very specific about the fields that you want it to retrieve. So, ideally, your retrieval function should allow the caller to be specific about the information to be retrieved. However, since your function returns a "snapshot class" and not a result-set (or a map of field name, field value pairs) you cannot have this.

So, you have to have an entirely different data retrieval function for each usage scenario, returning an entirely different "snapshot class" containing only the fields that are pertinent. Whether these functions all invoke a single complicated function that does the job for all scenarios is an internal implementation detail.